# ¿Cómo evitar que se muestre en una consulta los registros que contengan el campo "code" repetido?

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla pivote donde guardo registros, hay registro que tienen un mismo código (Pertenecen a la misma transacción) necesito que en la consulta no se muestren repetidos.

```
Id - code - serial
1  - XCV  - 123456
2  - NHV  - 147852
3  - NHV  - 154657
4  - ÑLO  - 147100
```

En ese ejempo requiero no mostrar los dos registros (2  - NHV  - 147852 y 3  - NHV  - 154657) solo uno ya que ambos pertenecen a la misma transacción

tengo lo siguiente: `$badges = Badge::distinct('code')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);` y no funciona, también intenté con unique() pero solo funciona para `collections`

Comment: Con uno te refieres a cualquiera? O quieres uno en especifico?

Comment: Es necesario que tengas que seleccionar serial también? Si haces esto, funcionará: `Badge::select('code')->distinct('code')`, pero si obligatoriamente necesitas agregar otras columnas, entonces debes usar `groupBy` en lugar de `distinct`

Comment: Sí, tengo otras columnas

Answer (score 0):

veo que lo que hace tu consulta solo es ordenar, pero no verificar cuales son los repetidosm.

Espero esto te sirva.

```
  $badg= Badge::distinct('code')->get();
  $badges = $badg->unique('code');
```

Saludos.